# Is it possible to match two wordlist in Ruta

Tags: mapping, uima, ruta

I need to match the values of two wordlist(i.e, 1st position of Wordlist1 with 1st position of Wordlist2)Like mapping 1st element of one list to 1st element of another list.

Sample wordlist1:

```
A
B
E
C
C
```

Sample wordlist2:

```
A92.8
B49.4
E16.0
C16.9
C49.4
```

First I need to find the Wordlist1 content in the document and then I need to match it with Wordlist2 (For example A with A92.8,B with B49.4 .....).Then I need to add the matched values as feature.Is it possible?

```
WORDLIST WL1List='WL1.txt';

DECLARE WL1(STRING replace);

Document{ -> MARKFAST(WL1,W1List)};


WORDLIST WL2='WL2.txt';

DECLARE WL2;

Document{ -> MARKFAST(WL2,WL2List)};



//MATCH
DECLARE MATCHED;
Some matching process.........{->MARK(MATCHED)};



BLOCK(foreach) WL1{}
{    
STRING matchrepl;

MATCHED{->MATCHEDTEXT(matchrepl)};

WL1{->WL1.replace=matchrepl};
}

WL1{->WL1.replace="NEED TO REPLACE"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conversion.csv:

```
A;A92.8
B;B49.4
E;E16.0
C;C16.9
C;C49.4
```

Script:

```
WORDTABLE conversion = 'conversion.csv';
DECLARE Annotation Conversion(STRING match);
Document{->MARKTABLE(Conversion, 1, conversion, "match" = 2)};
```

Comment: I have an another consequence in this answer C should match both C16.9 & C49.4

Comment: How is it possible?

Comment: Its not possible with the current implementation of WORDTABLE. You need some workaround like two features, which is of course not really a good solution There are plans to imporve this in Ruta. Normally, in this situation, the ConceptMapper is applied instead of WORDTABLE.

Comment: What is mean " need some workaround like two features"?

Comment: Something like `DECLARE Annotation Conversion(STRING match1, STRING match2);
Document{->MARKTABLE(Conversion, 1, conversion, "match1" = 2, "match2" = 3)};`. This is of course not desirable and you would need to change your csv files.

Comment: yeah its not desirable.Okay Thanks PETER:)